# Generics: can an interface be interogated to find T

Tags: c#, generics

I have completely re-written this hoping to make my question clearer.  I have chosen the concept of services making use of repositories in my example code.

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
    // Example entity could be:
    class Book : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Magazine : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntities();
    }

    interface IBooksRepository : IRepository<Book> { }
    interface IMagazineRepository : IRepository<Magazine> { }

    class DataStore<TEntity> where TEntity: class, IEntity
    {
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetFromStore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        DataStore<TEntity> _dataStore;

        public RepositoryBase()
        {
            _dataStore = new DataStore<TEntity>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntities()
        {
            return _dataStore.GetFromStore();
        }
    }

    class BookRepository : RepositoryBase<Book>, IBooksRepository { }
    class MagazineRepository : RepositoryBase<Magazine>, IMagazineRepository { }

    abstract class ServiceBase<IEntityRepository, TEntity>
        where IEntityRepository : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        IEntityRepository _repository;
        public ServiceBase(IEntityRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntitiesFromRepository()
        {
            return new List<TEntity>();
        }
    }

    class BookService : ServiceBase<IBooksRepository, Book>
    {
        public BookService(IBooksRepository bookRepository)
            : base(bookRepository)
        { }
    }
    class MagazineService : ServiceBase<IMagazineRepository, Magazine>
    {
        public MagazineService(IMagazineRepository magazineRepository)
            : base(magazineRepository)
        { }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aBookService = new BookService(new BookRepository());
        var aMagazineService = new MagazineService(new MagazineRepository());

        var books = aBookService.GetEntitiesFromRepository();
        var magazines = aMagazineService.GetEntitiesFromRepository();

    }
}
```

This all works fine and perhaps it is valid to ask why I want to change this. Mainly I am just curious if I can make this more neat.  It is more a point of curiosity that one of functional correctness I suppose.

Both IBookRepository and IMagazineRepository  know which concreate type they represent 'Book' and 'Magazine'

When I define my concreate services:  BookService and MagazineService I have to specify the type as well as the interface:

```
class BookService : ServiceBase<IBooksRepository, Book>{}
class MagazineService : ServiceBase<IMagazineRepository, Magazine>{}
```

I wondered if I could simplify thier signatures as the Interfaces already know The type I am expecting Book or Magazine.

Can I extract the Entity Type from the inteface such that I no longer need to specify the type when creating concreate service types?

As I pondered this,  I discovered a deeper issue with my knowledge of C#:

What exactly is the type of 'thing'  that the generic system is looking for between those angle brackets: `IEnumerable<TThisThing>`.

When I look at intellisense is says `T` is the type of objects to enumerate.

So as an experiment I grabbed the type of `MyType`:

```
Type typeOfMyType = instanceOfMyType.GetType();
IEnumerable<typeOfMyType> enumerable = new List<typeOfMyType>(); //crude example.
```

Now of course this does not work. So what kind of thing is `TThisThing` that works between the angle brackets?

Comment: *which implements that specific interface. `class SomeClass<IMySpecificInterface>`* ... could you please fix the declaration, to let code and intention meet according to language specs?

Comment: I don't understand. _You_ know the type when you declared the specific interface `IMySpecificInterface`. So use the same type in the class.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I would if I understood what you meant, sorry!

Comment: @John You say `SomeClass` implements `IMySpecificInterface`. According to the code, it in fact does **not** implement the interface, it uses the interface as a generic type parameter. Implementing the interface would look like `class SomeClass : IMySpecificInterface`

Comment: I get it.  I realised I tried to simplify way to much,  I am putting together a console app and will re-write this shortly.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way of extracting this information so that I can forgo the
>   inclusion of 'MyType' in the class definition and use the discovered
>   TMyType in the example method?

Yes, you simply need to define the generic type parameter in the methods name:

```
public IEnumerable<TMyType> GetMyTypes<TMyType>()
{
     // get list of TMyType instances;
     return list;
}
```

If you don't want to use a generic type parameter *at all*, you'll have to defer to reflection, and you won't be able to use a compile-time generic type such as returning an `IEnumerable<T>`.

> So what kind of thing is `TThisThing` that works between the angle
>   brackets?

`TThisThing` should be a compile-time known type parameter. When you use `Type typeOfMyType = instanceOfMyType.GetType();`, the type of `instanceOfMyType` is only known at *run-time*.

For example:

```
var obj = new SomeClass<Foo>();
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = obj.GetMyTypes<Bar>();
```

Where `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
public class Foo { }
public class Bar { }
```

Comment: On the first part I could do what you suggest, but that means specifying the TMyType where ever I call the method,  By specifying at the class level I don't need to do this. From your response I am guessing that the real answer to my question Can I extract the info from the interface == NO you cannot.  would that be correct?

Comment: @John You can lose the generic type parameter if you defer to using reflection, but then you won't be able to know the actual type you're returning at compile time, meaning you won't be able to use return an `IEnumerable<TMyType>`.